# Get Node Author's Name in Custom Block

Tags: nodes, 8, blocks

In the admin area, to create a custom block, I go to:

```
Structure, Block layout, + Add custom block.
```

Once I create the custom block in the UI, I see a textarea field called "Body" where I can enter content.

How can I dynamically render the node author's name and profile picture in my custom block. I know I can type it in, but I would like to be able to insert some code (PHP, Twig or token) so that it pull's the author's name and profile image dynamically and prints it on the block. I do not want to use a views block, but a custom block instead.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using a view block and going with a custom block instead.

Answer (score 7):

One way to go about this is [block preprocess function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!block!block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/8.2.x) to retrieve the block's current node context & insert the relevant variables to be used by your Twig template. For example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for block.html.twig.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
  if (!is_null($node)) {
    $uid = $node->getOwnerId();
    $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($uid);
    if (!is_null($user)) {
      $username = $user->getDisplayName();
      $variables['$username'] = $username;
      // {{ username }} will be available within block.html.twig.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can do `$node->getOwner()->getDisplayName()`

Answer (score 0):

It's never being a good practice to add php code in block. You can use the below mention code to print a user image on nodes.

```
<?php
   $nid =  arg(1); 
   if($nid){
     $node = node_load($nid);
     $user = user_load($node->uid);
     print $user->name;
     print theme('user_picture', array('account' =>$user));
   }
?>
```